# display one page from a site on a different domain name

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have a site complete with CMS etc all working under one domain name. It turns out for legal reasons one page on this site has to sit on a different domain name. The page is hooked into the same CMS as the rest of the site (built using codeigniter). I don't want to have to do another installation just for this page.

Is there any simple way to display just this page under a different domain name without taking it out of the current application?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it a static page or one that changes frequently?

Comment: it's dynamic. I'm thinking maybe remapping the url vars and using  curl to get the desired page may be the best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at either (in order):

- an `include()`with correct php.ini configuration
- a `file_get_content()` and printing the variable into your page
- an `<iframe src="yoururl">` wich would be the easy peasy but unsafe way
- using the on-purprose `curl`library
- using `fopen()` wich theorically allows distant files to be opened, but based on my experience, it's not that reliable

Look at [this site](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx), it seems rather exhaustive regarding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the file

```
<?php include 'http://www.domain.com/url/to/file/page.html' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is a symlink, which is something I don't know too much about. My understanding is that the path displayed to the user does not in fact have to have anything to do with where the file is actually stored, meaning you can set this up to have a completely different URL while keeping it as part of your original application.

A simpler thing is doing a redirect...it's one line of code in your .htaccess file and you're good to go.

Comment: Something like this could work, however hosting platforms *(ie. cPanel, even on a dedicated server)* will jailshell accounts, preventing access *(with good reason)* to the local filesystem outside of that jailshell'd account's `home/` directory. This prevents something like a symlink from working.

Comment: wouldn't this make the whole site available seeing as all page requests are routed through a single php file in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

[include](http://php.net/include) is a possible solution depending on the format of the remote page *(ie, this won't work very well if the remote page has a full DOM structure, and you're trying to include the remote page within the DOM structure of your CMS page)*, however more information about that remote page would be needed to help determine if `include()` alone would be enough.

Regardless, if `include()` does, work, you must make sure `allow_url_include` in php.ini is enabled, as by default script execution will terminate when encoutering a remote URL `include` statement.